# Did I do something wrong here to warrant this comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was unaware that there was an IT Security subsite of SO, so I had asked a general security question (including some "how"s so I figured it would turn technical enough to be a SO queston) relating to a web application.

The question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304245/digitally-signing-a-process-within-a-web-application

I feel like I was getting vague answers, and my attempt to clarify resulted in:

> "I think we are getting out of sync. If this was a consult I could
>   quickly resolve the differences. But it isn't and I think we should
>   leave it at this for now."

So my attempt to clarify a question that he **was answering to**  essentially resulted in "I'm not consulting you, leave it"?

I under-use SO so I wouldn't be surprised if I had done something wrong or should have handled this differently.

Should I not be asking for advise here or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like he decided that helping you solve your problem was turning out to be a lot more work than he thought, and he just isn't willing to put in that much effort to try to resolve your problem, so he politely indicated that he wasn't going to participate any more.

Comment: As to what you did wrong, it would appear that your question is just Too Broad, and you're expecting way more information than answers on SO are designed to provide.  You should be breaking your problem down into smaller pieces, trying to solve those smaller pieces, and potentially asking about some of those individual and more *specific* problems as SE questions.

Comment: Thanks Servy, I'll try to be more specific and concise in the future.